# PHP __soapCall soapaction

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need some help, I have a web service with 2 operations with the same name `PostHours`, but this have 2 actions `ForStandardReport` and `ForSpecialReport` the XML of the web service WSDL is:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://company.net/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://company.net/">
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:message name="ForStandardReportSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="CallVendorCode" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="CallDate" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="BTNState" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="PromotionCode" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="ReportCode" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="Hours" type="s:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ForStandardReportSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="ForStandardReportResult" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ForSpecialReportSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="CallVendorCode" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="CallDate" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="BTNState" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="PromotionCode" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="ReportCode" type="s:string"/>
<wsdl:part name="Hours" type="s:int"/>
<wsdl:part name="ReportBy" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ForSpecialReportSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="ForSpecialReportResult" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="companyReportingWebServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="PostHours">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Post Hours</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:input name="ForStandardReport" message="tns:ForStandardReportSoapIn"/>
    <wsdl:output name="ForStandardReport" message="tns:ForStandardReportSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PostHours">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Post Hours using ReportBy criteria</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:input name="ForSpecialReport" message="tns:ForSpecialReportSoapIn"/>
    <wsdl:output name="ForSpecialReport" message="tns:ForSpecialReportSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="companyReportingWebServiceSoap" type="tns:companyReportingWebServiceSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="PostHours">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://company.net/ForStandardReport" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:input name="ForStandardReport">
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="ForStandardReport">
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PostHours">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://company.net/ForSpecialReport" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:input name="ForSpecialReport">
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="ForSpecialReport">
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:binding name="companyReportingWebServiceSoap12" type="tns:companyReportingWebServiceSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="PostHours">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.net/ForStandardReport" style="rpc" soapActionRequired="true"/>
    <wsdl:input name="ForStandardReport">
    <soap12:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="ForStandardReport">
    <soap12:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PostHours">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://company.net/ForSpecialReport" style="rpc" soapActionRequired="true"/>
    <wsdl:input name="ForSpecialReport">
    <soap12:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="ForSpecialReport">
    <soap12:body use="encoded" namespace="http://company.net/" encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="companyReportingWebService">
<wsdl:port name="companyReportingWebServiceSoap" binding="tns:companyReportingWebServiceSoap">
<soap:address location="http://reportingservice.services.company.net/ReportingService.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="companyReportingWebServiceSoap12" binding="tns:companyReportingWebServiceSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://reportingservice.services.company.net/ReportingService.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This is my code in PHP to call the web service:

```
<?php 
//webservice definition
$WebService="http://reportingservice.services.company.net/ReportingService.asmx?wsdl";
//parameters definition
$parameters = array();
$parameters['CallVendorCode'] = 'code';
$parameters['CallDate'] = '01/01/2014';
$parameters['BTNState'] = 'code';
$parameters['PromotionCode'] = 'cod';
$parameters['ReportCode'] = 'code';
$parameters['Hours'] = 1; 
$parameters['ReportBy'] = 'code';

// webservice invocation
$WS = new SoapClient($WebService);

// method response in object
$result = $WS->__soapCall('PostHours',$parameters);

//result
print_r($result);


 ?>
```

It works for the standard action but doesn't work for the other action even if I add the option of the soapaction in the __soapCall

```
 $result = $WS->__soapCall('PostHours',$parameters,array('soapaction' => 'http://company.net/ForSpecialReport'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$wsdl = 'http://reportingservice.services.company.net/ReportingService.asmx?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

//parameters definition
$parameters = array();
$parameters['CallVendorCode'] = 'code';
$parameters['CallDate'] = '01/01/2014';
$parameters['BTNState'] = 'code';
$parameters['PromotionCode'] = 'cod';
$parameters['ReportCode'] = 'code';
$parameters['Hours'] = 1; 
$parameters['ReportBy'] = 'code';

$responseStandardReport = $client->ForStandardReport($parameters);
//or
$responseSpecialReport  = $client->ForSpecialReport($parameters);

//AND

$resultStandardReport = $responseStandardReport->ForStandardReportResult;
//or
$resultSpecialReport = $responseSpecialReport->ForStandardReportResult;
```

Comment: the function I´m calling is PostHours not ForSecialReport but this function have 2 actions ForStandardReport and ForSpecialReport, and i dont know how to choose in this 2 soap actions, check the xml of the service